# FileIOException, file.length threw an exception

Tags: c#, file-io

I am creating a tempfile using C#.

```
public partial class frmResults : Form
{
    public static string caseFile = "";

    private void frmResults_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caseFile = CreateTempFiles();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(caseFile + ".rpt");

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            try
            {   
                if (fil.Length < 64000000)
                {
                    richTabular.LoadFile(caseFile + ".rpt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                } 
            }
            catch (IOException io)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(io.GetType().Name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static string CreateTempFiles()
        {
            string sPath;
            caseFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

            sPath = Path.GetTempPath();
            string workDir = sPath + "\\work\\";
            // create work directory
            if (!Directory.Exists(workDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workDir);
            }
            // create temp file name
            int i = 0;
            string tmpfileprefix = workDir + "Rdp";
            string tmpfilename = "";
            do
            {
                i++;
                tmpfilename = tmpfileprefix + i.ToString("D6");
            } while (File.Exists(tmpfilename + ".rpt"));

            caseFile = tmpfilename;
            return caseFile;
        }
    }
}
```

> `Error:fil.Length = 'fil.Length'` threw an exception of type  `'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'`
>   Could not find file `'C:\Users\sc\AppData\Local\Temp\\work\Rdp000001.rpt'`.

Also, `if (fil.Exists)` returns false.

Comment: The error message is so clear to understand what is wrong. Did you check whether that file exist in the specified location or not ?

Comment: It doesnt and I checked that. But not sure y it is not creating it

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your `CreateTempFiles()` will always return a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: You should make sure your code is actually syntactically correct before posting it here. You don't close the `frmResults` method, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message couldn't be more clear:

> Error:fil.Length = 'fil.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' Could not find file 'C:\Users\sc\AppData\Local\Temp\work\Rdp000001.rpt'.

So... it's not a valid File object, yet you call a method (Length) which requires it to be, so an exception was thrown.  Your file doesn't exist.

Comment: y it is not creating the tempfile.

Comment: @user575219: You are using two variables; `file` (which does exist) and `fil`.  `fil` is throwing the error.  Where is that coming from?

Comment: ok got it. unfair to have a -3. I am creating it correctly but not writing to it using Streamwriter which gave me an exception

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreateTempFiles` method only returns a file name to a temp file that has not been created yet.  No where in that method does it create the file.  Also, no where in that method does it get the name of an existing file, so it will always be a new file.  If you really want to be safe, though, you could add a `if(File.Exists(caseFile + ".rpt"))` check around where you check its length.